# Nivo Slider Links Not Working

Tags: css, nivo-slider

The issue I'm running into now is that Nivo Slider isn't linking any of the photos in the slider. Originally it was, I had around 14 pictures in the slider that linked to a post that had a full gallery embedded inside. I had used a "fixed" size for the gallery but the issue was that when you use Fixed it doesn't work on mobile.

I took the images into Illustrator and cropped them all to the correct size for the front-page slider and used the regular slider settings. Now though none of the links work at all. I've not found anything that would work yet and have tried a few different things. The biggest issue I've seen is that the anchor for the link (Which is invisible) Somehow is somewhere else and doesn't span the entire image. I inserted some CSS into "Advanced CSS Editor" to try and fix it, This worked for the last "Fixed" slider but not now.

```
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
background:white; 
filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
opacity: 0;
z-index: 8;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute; 
}
```

For reference, here is the website I'm currently working on. The slider is the 2nd shortcode section down. Featuring "Unit 108"

http://www.morissette.properties/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There seems to be an issue with the Nivo Slider Gallery Configuration. You need to paste your link into the “Link” section and not the “CUSTOM URL” section. Second, You will need to make sure that its ONLY pasted into the “LINK” section of the image. Third, You will need to save the gallery after EACH IMAGE LINK HAS BEEN PASTED into the “link” section of the image information. DO NOT CLICK OFF THE IMAGE, otherwise your URL could disappear.

Maybe this is just with me, I hope so for the sake of everyone else but this is kind of ridiculous. Definitely not worth the money to go pro.

Have a great day everyone!